# ActiveAdmin form issue (has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm having an issue with ActiveAdmin.

I have the following models:

template.rb

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :template_questions
  has_many :questionnaires
  attr_accessible :category, :string
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_questions
end
```

template_question.rb

```
class TemplateQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  attr_accessible :number, :question
end
```

And this active admin resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Template do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :category
    end
    f.inputs "Questions" do
      f.has_many  :template_questions do |j|
        j.input :question
      end
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

When i'm on the form in the ActiveAdmin interface I see the fields for title and category properly, then on the questions section I get a button to add a question but when clicked it does nothing.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You normally need to add your attributes to attr_accessible, so lets add

```
attr_accessible :category, :string, :template_questions_attributes
```

Comment: This wan't my main issue, turned out to be something with javascript. But thanks a lot this really helped me later on!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Can you please tell us what the "something with javascript" was?

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head on the wall until I saw an [open issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1813) on the active admin github

The solution is to rollback from active admin 0.5.1 to 0.5.0